# How to build database structure of users data?

Tags: mongodb, api, database-design

I want to create a simple platform, where users can fastly create CRUD endpoints without any code. The user in the form enters some information about the entity

- fields,
- type of each field,
- default values and etc ...

for example, a user creates a ToDo entity with fields `{task: String, status: String, createdAt: Date, ...})`
and the platform generates CRUD API endpoints( POST, GET, PUT, DELETE ) for that ToDO entity. After that, the user can easily use those endpoints on his frontend project or in testing purposes. Each user can create more than one entity.

My question is how to correctly store all that data that the users will generate via those endpoints in my database(MongoDB). Should I create a separate collection for each user Entity, or there will be one collection, with special indices and it will be enough. Maybe any other approaches there are, that can be helpful. Any ideas are welcome. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think you can create a separate collection of each entity as storing them in one collection won't create a logical grouping